# Certificate SAN support regexp stemming?

Tags: ssl-certificate, regex, subject-alternative-names

Searched on this, but can't find any clear answer - can a certificate SAN contain a name like "citrix*.domain.com", to permit use with citrixdirector.domain.com and citrixprod.domain.com, for example?

Answer (score 2):

The current RFC governing checking of wildcards in DNS SANs is [RFC 6125, Section 6.4.3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6125#section-6.4.3).

According to those rules, a DNS SAN such as "citrix*.domain.com" is permitted.  The catch, however, is that the RFC uses the `MAY` language, which means that it is up to the specific cert-checking client implementation whether it will check/allow such wildcards.  Thus the *real* answer to your question will come down to the clients which are verifying your certs, *e.g.* browsers, client libraries, *etc etc*.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Certificate issuers might also have their own restrictions on the SAN they accept.